# Creating stages based on parameter name

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I want to setup APIGateway using CloudFormation. I have template ready with default stage but I want to create stage `test` or `prod` based on input parameter (that will be entered while creating the stack in CF UI).

if the input parameter is `prod` I want to create stage with different `burst`, `caching` and other properties.

if the input parameter is `test`, I want to keep everything default.

I know how to take in input parameters and provide only `test` & `prod` in drop down list. But how would i make `if`/`else` block in CF template to customize my stages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CloudFormation, you do this using [Conditions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html). Here's a template snippet that will set `CacheClusterEnabled` to `true` and `ThrottlingBurstLimit` to `999` only when `EnvType` is set to `prod`:

```
Parameters: 
  EnvType: 
    Description: Environment type.
    Default: test
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: 
      - prod
      - test
    ConstraintDescription: must specify prod or test.
Conditions: 
  ProdEnv: !Equals [ !Ref EnvType, prod ]
Resources:
  Stage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      CacheClusterEnabled: !If [ProdEnv, true, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
      MethodSettings: 
        - 
          ResourcePath: "/"
          HttpMethod: "GET"
          ThrottlingBurstLimit: !If [ProdEnv, 999, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
      # ...
```

Note that [`AWS::NoValue`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-novalue) prevents the property from being set at all when used in an [`Fn::If`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if) function, so the defaults would be used when `EnvType` is not `prod`.

Comment: Thanks. So let's say i set up this condition `"Conditions":{"CreateProdStage" : {"Fn::Equals": [{"Ref":"EnvType"}, "prod"]}},` and now i want to create `test` stage. How can i **negate** `CreateProdStage` condition

Comment: To negate a condition, you can: 1. Swap the second (true) and third (false) values in the `Fn::If` array; 2. Use [`Fn::Not`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-not)  to create a separate inverse Condition: `NotCreateProdStage: !Not [ Condition: CreateProdStage ]`.

Comment: I used `"Condition":{"Fn::Not": [{"Condition": "CreateProdStage"}]},` and got error that says `Template validation error: Template format error: Every Condition member must be a string.`

Comment: You can't use the `Fn::Not` function directly in a resource's `Condition` association; the negation must be defined as a separate condition (in the `Conditions` section), then you can reference the new Condition in the Resource as a string.